# FontAwesome twitch icon not showing but other icons work fine

Tags: html

My FontAwesome twitch icon isn't showing. It was completely fine before and now it just randomly disappeared. I haven't changed anything.

Here is my html code:

```
        <div class="text-center center-block" style="margin-top:-40px;"><br/>
            <h1>Follow us!</h1>
            <a href="http://facebook.com/facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-4x"></i></a>
            <a href="https://plus.google.com/u/google/"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-4x"></i></a>
            <a href="http://twitter.com/twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-4x"></i></a>
        <br/>
            <a href="http://steamcommunity.com/groups/steam"><i class="fa fa-steam-square fa-4x"></i></a>
            <a href="http://youtube.com/youtube"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-4x"></i></a>
            <a href="http://twitch.tv/twitch"><i class="fa fa-twitch fa-4x"></i></a>
        </div>
```

I don't understand why it randomly disappeared. I have the latest Font Awesome and have included it in my header like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/font-awesome-4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

All the other icons work completely fine. I can by the way still click on the twitch link but the icon is invisible. I also already tried clearing my cache and another browser.

Comment: Well it works for me, maybe it would be worth checking some of points on official [troubleshooting page](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting)

Comment: Yeah I checked, none of it fixes my issue. I'm really confused, it was working fine, then just nothing..

Answer (score 3):

On the Font Awesome page, in the Brand Icon's section, it says:

Warning!

Apparently, Adblock Plus can remove Font Awesome brand icons with their "Remove Social Media Buttons" setting. We will not use hacks to force them to display. Please report an issue with Adblock Plus if you believe this to be an error. To work around this, you'll need to modify the social icon class names.

Comment: Hey, yeah I'm aware of this. I had adblock disabled the entire time so it's not the issue.

Comment: Just to make sure I completely disabled adblock to no avail.

Comment: This was my issue, thanks for the reminder (about Ad Block)!

Answer (score 0):

I has the same problem and it was an outdated version of Font Awesome who was loading after the updated version

Answer (score 0):

Well, this question is old and probably some of the answers, but for those that are using the new version of Font Awesome like v5 and having the same issues, the current version as at when I am writing this is `v5.0.13`.

Make sure that you set the CSS to `font-weight:900`

e.g. 
`i.fab {font-weight:900}`

Please note that the `font-weight` is not `bold` but `900`.

This worked for me!

For more info visit [Troubleshooting Page for Font Awesome](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/wiki/Troubleshooting#im-using-custom-css-classes-with-font-awesome-5-and-solid-icons-dont-show-up)